# Error: DT_WSTR to Uniqueidentifier, what is going on?

Tags: ssis, type-conversion, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am currently trying to convert an int field into a Uniqueidentifier, doing so by first converting the int into a (DT_WSTR, 100)

(Note: i have also tried (DT_STR) )

i have tried both the Derived Column and the Convert Data Transformations, but i always get an error when converting the then String to a GUID.

Here is what I have Already Tried:

```
 NameOfDer.C                      Expression                               Data Type

 1)ID_String              (DT_WSTR, 100)ID_Int                        Unicode character string

-Below is where the error occurs- 
2) GUIDTESTEST     (DT_GUID)("{" + [ID_String] + "}")                   UniqueIdentifier
```

i have also tried it like this: (DT_GUID) [ID_String]  (-Without the curly braces), but it failed just as bad.

Does anyone have an idead of what is Happening, i have also looked the data up on DataViewer after they are converted to Strings, and they all seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS you can't convert integer to GUID.

GUID has format `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`. So integer 5 can't be fit in that format.

Some guy [did it with sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078209/sql-server-2008-convert-from-guid-to-bigint-and-back), but if this don't gonna loose information?

The best thing what you can do, just generate real GUID for your rows.